# Create a column using two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes below. I need to add a column to a dataframe from another dataframe.

DataFrame 1:

```
index   A       
 0      UK
 1      RSA
 2      US
```

DataFrame 2 :

```
index  B
 0     UK 
 1     CF
 2     AT
```

I need output like below.

```
index   A    B
  0     UK   UK
  0     UK   CF
  0     UK   AT
  1     RSA  UK
  1     RSA  CF
  1     RSA  AT
  2     US   UK
  2     US   CF
  2     US   AT
```

I tried merge, concat, and join, but it didn't workout. Please help me on this.

Comment: @jdehesa , if this is the duplicate question , hw do i get the key column for my question from the answer which is there in the duplicate one , and this is just an example and i have 100 customers in my excel file who has  different values for each customer

Comment: Try with `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['UK', 'RSA', 'US']}); df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['UK', 'CF', 'AT']}); df1['key'] = 1; df2['key'] = 1; result = pd.merge(df1, df2).drop('key', 1)`